# how to reference a specific cell in a table view with static cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a view that will function in a similar fashion as the Calendar "Add Event" view.

I have a grouped static table view with different sections. I am trying to make this function the same way as the "Add Event" in that it shows/hides detail rows as you click on them.

For an example of what I am trying to do, click on the "Starts" row in the "Add Event" view.

In order to accomplish this I need to have the detailed rows hidden at first, and as the user taps on the row have it show the row below it to show the detailed content.

Let's say row #3 in my table view is the summarized row (the one corresponding to the "Starts" row in the "Add To" view), and row #4 in my table view is the detailed view with a full date picker.

How can I reference a particular static row, for example row number 4 in the table, so that I can set it default not show? Second, how can I best show it upon tap on row number 3?

I know this is fairly basic, but I appreciate any help!

Comment: With static cells, you can make IBOutlets to them from your controller, and access them like any other UI element.

Comment: That's a great point! It appears if setting the cell to hidden still leaves the white space, so it seems I have to set the height to 0 instead. However, height is not part of the cell. Do you know how I would get the height of the row the cell belongs to?

Comment: Even though static cells don't use the table view data source methods, you can use the delegate methods -- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: is the one you want to set the height of the cells by indexPath

Comment: I still actually haven't gotten to a working solution on this...Do you have a code sample by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good example of table view with static cells.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you use 1 custom cell for its summary and for its detail and manage the hiding within the cell view. Second, the problem/advantage with `UITable`s is that they reuse cells so for example when pointing/referencing to a cell at row #4 later you will pointing at row#12 when you scroll down and getting strange results. Instead of referencing a cell you should reference the object that feeds the cell.

Comment: Since I am referencing static cells, does this really apply, though? Also, just so I can learn - why do you suggest having both the detail and the summary in one custom cell? It appears (based on the layout) that Apple uses two rows in the "Add Event" view? Please also see my comment above to rdelmar, to see if you have something to add...Thanks to both of you for trying to help!

Comment: If you are using static cells you shouldn't have trouble referencing any cell. There so much ways you can reference them. And if it's a static table it actually might be even better to have detail and summary in separate cells.